# I got connection error it does not read data from database

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin forms, I tried to make a login form using `MVVM`. When I write the code there is no error but it does not give the desired output.

```
public Command Login
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(() =>
        {
            var d = database.loggin(Usernamelogin, Passwordlogin);

            if (d != null)
            {
                if (d.UserName == Usernamelogin && d.Password == Passwordlogin)
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Notification", "Successfully Login", "Okay");

                }
                else
                {
                    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Notification", "Error Login", "Okay");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Notification", "No data", "Okay");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is login command

```
public Register_person loggin(string mail,string pass )
{
    return Conn.Table<Register_person>().FirstOrDefault(t => (t.Email == mail && t.Password == pass));
}
```

I only get the display message when the database is null statement. I cannot find why.

Comment: What error you are getting? Can you share the error message here?

Comment: You’re doing comparisons twice, and one for email and another for username. Doesn’t seem sensible at all. But first explain exactly what the problem is, what should happen, what happens instead etc. We don’t know what “desirable output” would be.

Comment: thanks for quick reply, the code is running there is no syntax error.but problem is i need to catch some data from my data base . when i use known data for username and password it should successfully login instead that it gives no data that the problem i faced

Comment: Be sure the local database has saved data.And checking code getting data from database.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the exact error message that you encountered, or expected results + actual results.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ICommand Login { get; set; }
```

then add a constructor

```
public LoginViewModel()
    {
        Login = new Command(Login_Clicked);
    }
```

then create a method Login_Clicked

```
 private void Login_Clicked()
    {

        database = new Database();

        var Logindata = database.GetUsername(_usernamelogin);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_usernamelogin) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_passwordlogin))
        {


            // your code

        }
        else
        {

            if (Logindata != null)
            {
                if (Logindata.UserName == _usernamelogin && Logindata.Password == _passwordlogin)
                {

                      // your code

                }

                else
                {
                      // your code
                }
            }
            else
            {
                   // your code
            }

        }

    }
```

linc query

```
 return Conn.Table<your Table name>().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Email == mail);
```

I extract email in the table